# Rewrite an if statement into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So I currently wrote an if/elif statement but I can't seem to get how to rewrite into a dictionary.

I have this currently.

```
def determineRank(years):
    if years == 1:
        return "Freshman"
    elif years == 2:
        return "Sophmore"
    elif years == 3:
        return "Junior"
    else:
        return "Senior"
```

I currently have:

```
dYear = {"Freshman":1, "Sophmore":2, "Junior":3, "Senior":4}
```

but I'm not exactly sure where to go from here.

Comment: `dict_year = {1: 'Freshman', 2: 'Sophmore', 3: 'Junoir', 4: 'Senior'}` and you can do `dict_year.get(1)` to get `Freshman`

Comment: What are your attempts? You should show them in your question so that people can give specific guidance on why it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review [ask] and, as @roganjosh mentioned, show us what you've tried.

Comment: Don't post as a comment. Edit it into your question.

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Have you considered using [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Your function body would look like this:

```
rank = {
  1: "Freshman",
  2: "Sophomore",
  3: "Junior",
  4: "Senior"
}
return rank[years]
```

Note that this does not check the input for errors; if you feed it a 0 or 5, you'll get an access error.  I'll leave the checking as an exercise for the student.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary is backwards, and it should be a list or tuple.

```
def determineRank(years):
    return [None, 'Freshman', 'Sophomore', 'Junior', 'Senior'][years]
```

You can avoid having to create a new list or tuple on each call by binding it on definition as a default argument:

```
def determineRank(years, ranks=(None, 'Freshman', 'Sophomore', 'Junior', 'Senior')):
    return ranks[years]
```

You can avoid the extraneous `None` by using modulo arithmetic:

```
def determineRank(years, ranks=('Freshman', 'Sophomore', 'Junior', 'Senior')):
    return ranks[years%len(ranks)]
```

Note that your original code handles bad input more gracefully (but still incorrectly) by returning `'Senior'` for the 4th year *and all other inputs*, while the snippets above have various behaviors for incorrect inputs (like `20` or `'hello'`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `defaultdict`.

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: student = defaultdict(lambda: 'Senior')

In [3]: for k, v in ((1, 'Freshman'), (2, 'Sophmore'), (3, 'Junior')):
   ...:     student[k] = v
   ...:     

In [4]: student[1]
Out[4]: 'Freshman'

In [5]: student[2]
Out[5]: 'Sophmore'

In [6]: student[3]
Out[6]: 'Junior'

In [7]: student[4]
Out[7]: 'Senior'

In [8]: student[9]
Out[8]: 'Senior'
```